# Hurdle model for non-count continuous data with both positive and negative values

Tags: normal-distribution, stata, continuous-data, zero-inflation, rstan

I am aiming to estimate a hurdle model (where being non-zero is the hurdle) in the vein of Cragg. My data is both positive and negative where the data reflects the difference between a value reported initially and then in a follow-up.

The hurdle is effectively that an individual does not report the same value twice in a follow-up (i.e the difference values that I am using as my dependent variable are not 0). Having not reported the same value (i.e not being 0), I would like to estimate a normal regression model.

All the packages I have looked at (churdle in stata and pscl::hurdle in R) seem to focus on non-zero data. I am wondering if there is a way to do this for my type of data.

I have attempted to just simply estimate a probit on the likelihood of reporting 0 and then estimate my normal regression model for the observations where it does not equal 0 but this seems wrong. I imagine I would need to be adjusting my standard errors somehow.

Comment: Why do you want to model the difference follow-up - baseline and not model the follow-up with the baseline as a regressor?

Comment: Hi Utobi, I'd like to identify if the information is resulting in people 'changing their mind'. As such, I imagine there's some element of not bothering to change their mind, and then once they have changed it, id like to know if different treatments result in different changes. However, as you say, this could equivalently be constructed by putting the baseline on the RHS. My understanding is this doesn't change anything really since it's just an algebraic move from the LHS to to the RHS?

Comment: Modelling the difference is like modelling the level with the baseline having beta -1; So modelling the level is more general.